# What is virtuoso-nepomuk and how much harm could I do by uninstalling it?

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, package-management, 14.10

I am trying to solve what might be an unsolvable broken system. Apparently `virtuoso-nepomuk` is tripping up something in the upgrade process and causing an `unable to migrate to dependancy based boot sequencing` error (or something like that). From what I can tell `virtuoso-nepomuk` is the package that is not playing well.

Can I remove it? What will break if I do?

For what it is worth I seem to be running 12.04 shell but seeing the version report as 14.10 so...

EDIT: Apparently it is not installed so why would it cause problems?

EDIT: However the script is still reporting as broken in the logs with a missing end of LSB comment (whatever that is)

Comment: You could run `apt-get remove -s virtuoso-nepomuk` and see what happens. The `-s` means "simulate" and does just print terminal output but without touching the system. This way you can see which other packages would get removed with it.

Comment: And please provide full command outputs instead of interpreting and quoting some snippets of them. Thank you!

Comment: I would love to copy and paste everything but unless there is a way of doing this from TTY1 I cannot. This system is very broken.

Comment: If you a net connection, try and install `pastebinit` - since `apt` is giving you problems, try directly with `apt-get download pastebinit`, `sudo dpkg -i pastebinit*.deb`. Then you can pipe the output of any commands to `pastebinit` and it will create a paste (by default at http://paste.ubuntu.com).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it some sort of powerful SQL thing. I am not sure what exactly. However in this case the problem was that it was a leftover file in `/etc/init.d/` that famously gets in the way of upgrades. I moved it with `sudo mv /etc/init.d/virtuoso-nepomuk ~` which stuck it in my home folder to be dealt with later.